# how to get download bar height at the bottom of chrome?

Tags: javascript

When downloading something in Chrome, it shows a download bar that contains all the downloads. how to get download bar height at the bottom of Google Chrome using javascript?

I've tried `window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight` but the result is containing the menu bar, status bar, download bar, and the other bars.
how can I get only the bottom download bar?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `window.innerHeight` when there is no download bar minus the value when there is a download bar.  I think that's the only way.  Not sure, off hand, how that would be affected by window zoom.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get that piece of information. The browser will not disclose how much of the `window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight` is occupied by what. The image from the [MDN page for Window.innerHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight) shows it clearly:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Before any downloads occur in your app, `window.innerHeight` represents the height of the viewport.

After the download, `window.innerHeight` represents the height of the viewport plus the download bar.

So just subtract one from the other.

```
const heightBefore = window.innerHeight;

// code to handle downloads, e.g. click event listener

const heightAfter = window.innerHeight;

const heightOfDownloadBar = heightAfter - heightBefore;
```

There's no internal method so that's your best bet for a workaround.

Comment: This assumes that the user did not resize their browser and also that the download bar was previously off. But still, interesting hack.

Comment: The idea is that you run this code before and after any "download events" in your app. That will catch any resizing, or if the download bar is already visible. It's up to the OP to implement it properly though.

Comment: The problem is that we can't tell if the download bar is shown or not. and whenever the user opens the tab with my app I can't tell if the bar is shown or not. @Darren